# How to install GRUB in Ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: linux, boot, partitioning, debian, grub

I am trying dual boot Ubuntu with Windows 10. This installation was going Like Breeze until GRUB Installation.

Partition Specs:-

Boot was 100GB
Swap 16GB
Home ext4 100GB

All those partitions are NOT primary. Home Is Logical.

Comment: Debian already offers to install GRUB during the installation. What is your exact problem? And which Debian release are you interested in (there are differences)? There is no "Debian Dummy" release; the current stable release is Debian Jessie.

Comment: Debian 8: 8.5 Is The Version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: Install Ubuntu CD/USB Installer.

---

Step 2: Type `sudo apt-get grub`.

---

Step 3: Restart PC/Computer.

---

Step 4:Check All Your OS(s) Installed are Recognized.